What would your reflection look like if a mirror was going close to the speed of light?
What would your reflection look like if a mirror was going close to the speed of light?
Conditions: The mirror is a very long perfect mirror, lets say a light year long, moving close to the speed of light perpendicular to the line of sight the observer is looking. This is so that the distance between the mirror and the observer is constant but the mirror is still moving close to the speed of light.
My question is would you even see a reflection? Would the inertia given by the moving mirror to the bouncing light move your reflection along the mirror in the direction of it's movement?

If you stand before a mirror that is moving rapidly left-right or up-down, there is no effect. If the mirror approaches or recedes, then you get blueshifting and redshifting.
This may appear odd if you think of relativistic aberration: from the perspective of an ant on the mirror you are standing at a different angle compared to the rest case, and presumably the light ought to bounce in a different direction... but because again of aberration, the light leaving the mirror get un-aberrated. So you don't see anything odd.

Wouldn't such a mirror have a large "observed mass"?

Yes, but that mass does not play a part in the reflection for the basic thought experiment. For very light mirrors (relevant for thinking about relativistic lightsails) the reaction when light bounces off does matter, but the effect is minuscule unless the light is very intense. Also, it is better to think about it as relativistic momentum rather than mass.

If the mirror is perfect, its motion will have absolutely no effect on the reflection, so you won't be able to tell that it's moving.

Would the inertia given by the moving mirror to the bouncing light move your reflection along the mirror in the direction of it's movement?

The mirror will not impart any of its sideways momentum to the reflected light. The light's direction will get changed just as if the mirror were stationary. That is, the light's momentum in the perpendicular direction to the mirror will get reversed exactly, and its momentum in the parallel directions will be unchanged.

This is obviously not an easy experiment to perform. ;) However, we have performed similar experiments at lower speeds, using rotating mirrors, and using precise light beams and precise timings, to ensure that the light rays behave according to the laws of reflection, as expected.
FWIW, I first thought about this problem when I was a child travelling on a train. I noticed that the reflection of the sunlight off an adjacent rail seemed unaffected by my motion relative to the rail.

You seem to disagree about the red shift scenario in the other answer.

@Carl Anders is perfectly correct in saying "If the mirror approaches or recedes, then you get blueshifting and redshifting". However, in the OP's scenario there is no red or blue shift because "the distance between the mirror and the observer is constant".

What would you say would happen if it was more similar to a real life mirror, e.g. 99.9% reflective?

@AxisOmega Most real mirrors have their reflective layer behind a layer of glass (although telescope mirrors are first-surface mirrors). I expect that light travelling through the moving glass will experience some drag, similar to light travelling through moving water, as in the water experiment of Fizeau. FWIW, that experiment influenced Einstein's development of relativity much more than the Michelson-Morley experiment did.
